# using profile2 login information as billing information in commerce

Tags: commerce, users

I have a site where people able to buy anything are already loged in. How do I collect from profile2 and apply this information in commerce billing automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better to use Commerce Customer Profiles for that information.

Although "billing" is the default, you can add other groups of profile fields as types, e.g "Profile information" etc...

There's a module [commerce_customer_profile_type_ui](http://drupal.org/project/customer_profile_type_ui) that helps creating new profile types, else you can do it in code via the API.

Comment: okay..will I then be able to add taxonomy term for their preference which only shows up at registration?